# How to add user-created dictionary for elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, openshift, kubernetes-pvc

Installed Elasticsearch 7.17 in openshift from Operators , 3 pods. We need to add a hunspell dictionary for each pod. I use PVC for storage.

```
  volumeClaimTemplates:
        - metadata:
            name: elasticsearch-data
          spec:
            accessModes:
              - ReadWriteOnce
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 50Gi
            storageClassName: storagecluster-rbd
            volumeMode: Filesystem
          status: {}
```

Copying the directory with the dictionary files is not suitable because the dictionary files disappear after restarting the pod.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.